# Intersection of line and convex set

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, computational-geometry, computation-theory

Let X be a collection of n points in some moderate-dimensional space - for now, say R^5. Let S be the convex hull of X, let p be a point in S, and let v be any direction. Finally, let L = {p + lambda v : lambda a real number} be the line passing through p in direction v.

I am interested in finding a reasonably efficient algorithm for computing the intersection of S with L. I'd also be interested in hearing if it is known that no such algorithm exists! Note that this intersection can be represented by the (extreme) two points of intersection of L with the boundary of S. I'm particularly interested in finding an algorithm that behaves well when n is large.

I should say that it is easy to do this very efficiently in two dimensions. In that case, one can order the points of X in 'clockwise order' as seen from p, and then do binary search. So, the initial ordering takes O(n log(n)) steps and then further lookups take O(log(n)) steps. I don't see what the analogous algorithm should be in higher dimensions. Part of the problem is that a convex body in two dimensions has n vertices and n faces, while a convex body in 3 or higher dimensions can have n vertices but many, many more than n faces.

Comment: What language, platform or tool are you using to interpret this code/markup? "$X = { x_{1},\ldots,x_{n} }$"

Comment: By `$X \cap L$`, are you referring to the set of points that are in your original set `X`, and also on the line `L`? Wouldn't this be as simple as checking if each point in `X` satisfies the equation of `L`? I feel like I'm missing something fundamental.

Comment: Shrug.  I have no problem reading simple TeX, and I actually prefer it to reading mangled HTML math.

Comment: The fact that the OP is tempted to use Tex markup rather than code formatting is a strong indicator to me that this post should be in http://cs.stackexchange.com/ rather than stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, and thank you Douglas for the edit. Indeed this was supposed to be Latex. I hope it is easier to read now.

sykora: I may have written X \cap L for the intersection of X and L in the original. The intent (which is also the version left by Douglas) was to look for the intersection of S and L. This is harder, as it isn't so clear what equations to check.

Comment: @beaker: Why is that such a "strong indicator" to you?  You're liable to get a practically worthless answer complete with a worst-case asymptotic bound on the required number of rational number operations when you ask this sort of thing on cs; SO is for practical programming problems.

Comment: @tmyklebu It's just my interpretation of this answer on meta: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266344/1377097. I don't frequent cs, so I'll take your word on the type of answers found there, however discouraging it may be.

Comment: @beaker: It's not discouraging.  Theoretical computer science is just very, very divorced from the reality of programming.  Lots *and lots and lots* of important problems admit heuristics that run very fast and very well on any instance you're likely to want solved, but have some horrible, pathological worst case.

Comment: @tmyklebu That just further blurs the line between http://cs.stackexchange.com/ and http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/ :) Let's just answer all of 'em here...

Comment: @beaker: Not really.  cstheory is for research-level stuff.  Neither one is really for "I want something that works in practice."

Answer (score 2):

You can write a simple linear program for this.  You want to minimise/maximise lambda subject to the constraint that x + lambda v lies in the convex hull of your input points.  "Lies in the convex hull of" is coordinatewise equality between two points, one of which is a nonnegative weighted average of your input points such that the weights sum to 1.

As a practical matter, it may be useful to start with a handful of randomly chosen points, get a convex combination or a certificate of infeasibility, then interpret the cerificate of infeasibility as a linear inequality and find the input point that most violates it.  If you're using a practical solver, this means you want to formulate the dual, switch a bunch of presolve things off, and run the above essentially as a cutting plane method using certificates of unboundedness instead.  It is likely that, unless you have pathological data, you will only need to tell the LP solver about a small handful of your input points.

Comment: Thanks! I agree that it is possible to write a simple linear program for this. I didn't know if it was the best option. Certainly this will take at least n  log(n) steps to run (and I think much longer), while in 2-d you can get an ammortized cost of only log(n).

I like the idea of checking a small handful of random points first. If I was just trying to check that an individual point was in the convex hull, I agree that checking the condition a handful of points at a time would be `obviously' a good idea. Can you explain how this extends to calculating the intersection with a line?

Comment: Do you care about the worst case or do you care about actual performance?  Because I doubt you can do very well in the worst case.

Comment: I muddled the description a bit the first time.  You should probably just feed the LP solver all of your points.  If I wanted to feed it only a subset, I'd probably do a galloping search on lambda (doubling until you find a point outside the convex hull, then binary search in between), using said column generation scheme for each lambda considered.  I'm not actually sure right now that this trickery will solve your problem faster.

Comment: Thanks again. I care most about whatever `best practice' might be. Something like LP was the best I could come up with in high dimensions, but it was worse (both in theory and in practice) than another approach in dimension 2, and I thought there might be a way to beat it in high dimensions too. Unfortunately, LP isn't quite good enough to do what I want - I've been looking at n=10^10 points and then trying to solve the problem for 10^5 choices of (p,v). The 2-d algorithm handles this just fine, but my 5-d algorithm chokes... even for artificially nice data.

Comment: @l2c, keep in mind that the complexity of the convex hull (e.g. representation of its faces) is exponential in the dimensionality of the problem, so don't expect efficient solutions as in 2D. I think a linear program is a reasonable solution here

Comment: @l2c: I don't see a way to solve your problem that doesn't involve either extreme patience or extremely powerful computers.  Building a data structure on the convex hull in 5 dimensions seems harder, not easier, than the problem you're trying to solve.  If you can make do with upper and lower bounds on the min and max lambdas, you could get the outer bounds by doing a bunch of random projections onto 3-dimensional spaces and get the inner bounds by either the LP or convex hull data structure approach, but only on a modest random sample of your points.  I don't have any better ideas.